# E670002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL '' svn: E670002: Name or service not known errors

Tags: svn

While running the below command I get the following errors.

command:

```
svn co --username=anonymous --password=none https://openmodelica.org/svn/MetaModelica/trunk mmc
```

errors:

> svn: E670002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://openmodelica.org/svn/OpenModelica/trunk'
>
> svn: E670002: Name or service not known

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not really an answer, but double check the internet in general is working. I was on a vm trying to update and finally realized the network settings on the whole were wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue. In my case I was able to resolve the issue by mapping the `ip` and the `host name` in `/etc/hosts file`.

Comment: For me, this issue got resolved after removing the ip and host name from /etc/hosts.

Comment: Fixed it for me, although not clear how it worked before when the IP and name wasn't there, and it still works from other machines without it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Firewall or IPTables activated? i had the same issue and IPTables was blocking the connection. so i needed to open the required ports in iptables.

Answer (score 1):

This probably was due to network errors

The answer was useful, as I got here when a coworker was having difficulty
( they ended up using the ip address to access the repository
  since ping with the name didn't work either )

Comment: This was issue for me. Tried svn up about 30min after initial error and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when connected to my company's VPN. Disconnecting from the VPN cleared it. Although it's possible that reconfiguring my VPN may also clear the problem, I do not have permissions to make those types of changes, only the IT department does.

Note that some services that host SVN repositories may have ICMP echo messages disabled, so pinging will time out whether the connection is available or not.